# Simultaneously exporting from multiple shapes by expression in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, expression

I am working with OSM road shapes, there are 64 shapes for the whole American continent. I use "Select Features using an expression" tool to export selected classes from the "highway" field. (Expression is `"highway" IN  ( 'motorway' , 'motorway_link' , 'primary' , 'primary_link' , 'trunk' , 'trunk_link' )`).

Is there any better and quicker method to do this instead of manual routine?

[image: shapes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **Extract by expression** tool which can be found in the *Processing Toolbox* and run it as a batch process:

[image: Extract by expression]

Comment: @Vitruvius - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)